# Starting a service on entering Geofence in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-geofence

How can I start a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on entering a [Geofence](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence) in android.
I need to download data from the internet on entering a Geofence.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download data using service.

Please visit below link:

http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android